# CSS properties, decorating a link

Tags: css

My CSS contains

```
a.myLink {
    hover {font-size: 24;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
}
```

I'd like to be able to reference it using

```
<a class="myLink" href="http://myUrl" target='_new'>myName</a>
```

However, CSS does not get recognize this call.

What am I missing here? Please advise.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
a.myLink {
    hover {font-size: 24;
```

Is not correct syntax, look at using

**Link Properties:**

```
       a.myLink {
           /* Some formatting for the link here */
       }
```

**Hover Properties:**

```
    a.myLink:hover {
       font-size: 24;
       font-weight: bold;
       color: red;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
a.myLink:hover {
    font-size: 24;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
}
```

if you want to add these styles when someone hovers over the link.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have any asteriks(*) in your HTML code. Maybe you only added those for this demonstration?

But for a hover effect you want something like this:

```
a.myLink:hover { /*code here */ }
```

just a bit of mixed up syntax.

Comment: because I edited the post and took them out... can't put bold tag inside of your code on stackoverflow